# linux logfile to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, sed

Hi I have the following logfile:

log.file
The data is like this:

```
 [string;int;string,string2;int2;string2]
 [string3;int3;string3,string4;int4;string4]
```

I need to get it in a pandas dataframe like this:

```
 string int string
 string2 int2 string2
 string3 int3 string3
 string4 int4 string4
```

I though to first use Sed in a subprocess to remove the "[" and replace the "]" with a comma, and the use pd.read_csv to get the separate values in a dataframe and then transpose to get it in a column. However then I get the following dataframe:

```
 ""
 string;int;string
 string2;int2;string2
 string3;int3;string3
 string4;int4;string4
 unnamed:5
```

How can I split this column in multiple columns based on the ";" I saw some posts about splitsing columns but they didn't work for me.

Somebody have an idea? Or maybe even a easier solution to get the data in a dataframe?

Comment: have you tried `pd.read_csv(delimiter=";")`?

Comment: It's great that you've given a description of the data, but can you try to do up some example lines where the `int2` values are actually ints? So like `[cat;44;dog;dog;32;mouse]`. That way people can test their solutions on data that looks like yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple replace with `awk` should do:

```
awk '{gsub(/[][]/,"");gsub(";",FS);sub(",",RS)}1' file
string int string
string2 int2 string2
string3 int3 string3
string4 int4 string4
```

Or with `sed`:

```
sed 's/[][]//g;s/;/ /g;s/,/\n/' file
string int string
string2 int2 string2
string3 int3 string3
string4 int4 string4
```

Comment: I adjusted it a little bit because the number of variables in each line can change. I did it like the answer I posted. But thanks

Answer (score 0):

assuming file is opened as `f`:

```py
for line in f:
    tokens=line[1:-1].split(',')
    for token in tokens:
        items=token.split(';')
        print " ".join(items)
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems like in your file:

- fields are semi-colon delimited
- lines are comma delimited
- each pair of lines is enclosed in `[]`

based on that, I would recommend

- read file into memory as string
- replace the `[]` with spaces
- replace commas with newline characters
- write the string to a file
- read from file using `pandas.read_csv` with `sep=','`

Answer (score 0):

With help from Jotne I made it work like this:

```
// in shell
sed -i $'s/[][]//g;s/,/\\\n/g' filename
// in python
pd.read_csv(filename, sep= ';',skipinitialspace=1, names=header_row)
```